# NodeJS with express: Header undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http, http-headers

I'm using Microsoft Flow to send an HTTP POST request to my server. The request body contains a custom header called "Email-To", which has a string as it's value. Here is the body:

```
{
  "$content-type": "multipart/form-data",
  "$multipart": [
    {
      "headers": {
        "Email-To": "test@email.no",
        "Content-Disposition": "form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=901210.xlsx"
      },
      "body": {
        "$content-type": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
        "$content": "content"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

When the request reaches my NodeJS server, I want to retrieve the value from the header.

```
app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.headers("Email-To"))
  console.log(req.get("Email-To"))
});
```

Both the logs will always print "undefined". I tried debugging it further by looking at the request object itself, under headers. It doesn't seem to have the header.

```
0|server  |   headers:
0|server  |    { host: 'my_ip',
0|server  |      'accept-language': 'en-US',
0|server  |      'user-agent':
0|server  |       'azure-logic-apps/1.0 (workflow aa9d5e05e9b54c478ccebf2412633add; version 08586366094673048593) microsoft-flow/1.0',
0|server  |      'x-ms-execution-location': 'westeurope',
0|server  |      'x-ms-workflow-id': 'aa9d5e05e9b54c478ccebf2412633add',
0|server  |      'x-ms-workflow-version': '08586366094673048593',
0|server  |      'x-ms-workflow-name': '010bf24d-5a56-4053-8a39-e088e727cbf5',
0|server  |      'x-ms-workflow-system-id':
0|server  |       '/locations/westeurope/scaleunits/prod-48/workflows/aa9d5e05e9b54c478ccebf2412633add',
0|server  |      'x-ms-workflow-run-id': '08586365350241297663352938044CU52',
0|server  |      'x-ms-workflow-run-tracking-id': '2eec16eb-2f3f-4a87-a26d-683750ca20f5',
0|server  |      'x-ms-workflow-operation-name': 'HTTP',
0|server  |      'x-ms-workflow-subscription-id': 'b745f25e-91b5-4140-9d73-93b10b1dfb1d',
0|server  |      'x-ms-workflow-resourcegroup-name':
0|server  |       'B5EBEC49F06342E5B0E1F4E04C03D0B7-D8266BA594DC4A5DB55D7F31650FCD73',
0|server  |      'x-ms-tracking-id': 'aa92c109-151a-418c-8d01-754da7bc2c43',
0|server  |      'x-ms-correlation-id': 'aa92c109-151a-418c-8d01-754da7bc2c43',
0|server  |      'x-ms-client-request-id': 'aa92c109-151a-418c-8d01-754da7bc2c43',
0|server  |      'x-ms-client-tracking-id': '08586365350241297663352938044CU52',
0|server  |      'x-ms-action-tracking-id': 'f3a02477-227d-46cf-9105-228fe5c41f8d',
0|server  |      'x-ms-activity-vector': 'IN.0E',
0|server  |      'content-type':
0|server  |       'multipart/form-data; boundary="c859bba4-c9e1-4426-86ce-b3daf6ab74d9"',
0|server  |      'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
0|server  |      via: '1.1 my_ip (Apache/2.4.18)',
0|server  |      'x-forwarded-for': 'someones_ip',
0|server  |      'x-forwarded-host': 'my_ip',
0|server  |      'x-forwarded-server': 'my_ip',
0|server  |      connection: 'Keep-Alive',
0|server  |      'content-length': '43929' }
```

After reading up on headers, I'm pretty sure any key-value pair that doesn't conflict with the other headers should work fine, yet my "Email-To" header doesn't seem to work. Any ideas why?

Edit: CORS (using wildcard)

```
Sending POST request to http://my_ip/node/upload

Fired XHR event: loadstart
Fired XHR event: readystatechange
Fired XHR event: error

XHR status: 0
XHR status text: 
Fired XHR event: loadend
```

Edit 2: I tried sending the POST request using postman, and it worked just fine. I could retrieve the header like normal.

Edit 3: I add the CORS like so:

```
app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Email-To");

  console.log(req.headers("Email-To"))
  console.log(req.get("Email-To"))
});
```

Comment: it's `req.headers[Email-To]` not `req.header`, have you allowed these headers in CORS?

Comment: @AZ_ You're right, but I'm still getting undefined.

Comment: check your CORS policy

Comment: @AZ_ I've added the CORS result from test-cors.org to my original post

Comment: add the part of code where you are allowing CORS. are you using wildcard `*`? have you tried calling api in postman do you get the headers?

Comment: @AZ_ I'm using wildcard CORS. (res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");) Getting the header after sending the POST request with postman works.

Comment: what do you have with `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`?

Comment: @AZ_ I hadn't specified anything previously, but doing res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*") still gives me undefined when sending the request through Flow. It still works using postman.

Comment: Setting `"Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*"` has no meaning, you need specify it,`"Access-Control-Allow-Headers":"Email-To"`

Comment: @lx1412 Thanks. Still undefined when sending the request with Flow, and still works just fine with postman.

Comment: add the part of code where you are adding cors policy.

Comment: @AZ_ I've added the CORS implementation. I'm guessing having it in the same middleware shouldn't be an issue?

Answer (score 4):

Please use **lower-case name of param** when getting value from req.headers

```
app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
     console.log(req.headers["email-to"])) //email-to
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using square brackets, it should work.

```
app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
     console.log(req.headers["Email-To"]))
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm still getting undefined!

Comment: can you stringify the whole req in console.

Comment: I get this error: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Comment: Have anyone found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Add lines below and try again plz.

```
app.options('/upload', function(req, res) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','specify your origin');//do not use `*`!
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Email-To');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','POST');
  res.end();
});
```

Comment: This implementation also works completely fine when using postman, but I still get undefined on the "Email-To" header when sending the request through Microsoft Flow.

Comment: @AsgeirBjelland because cors is a security layer on the browser, that's why I asked you to check with the postman.

Comment: @AsgeirBjelland are there any other CORS middlewares?

Comment: @lx1412 There are no other CORS middlewares.

Answer (score 0):

try using arrow functions and square brackets

```
app.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
     console.log(req.headers["Email-To"]))
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that the name of the header was getting converted to a different naming convention. So, if I provide `redirectDomain`, it would be converted to `redirectdomain`. I've changed it as `Redirect-Domain` and read it as `redirect-domain`. Reading it as `Redirect-Domain` would probably work too.